# search and replace string using batch or perl script

Tags: batch, search, perl, string

How can i search for "//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt #10" and replace #10 with #15(set VARIABLE="#15") using batch commands and also **ignoring** spaces. #10 can be anything, **lets assume #XXX.**
example in command line is preferred.

testlog.txt

```
   //packages/thirdparty/release/config.txt                    #8
   //packages/thirdparty/release/config2.txt   #3
   //packages/thirdparty/release/config1.txt    #4
   //packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt            #10
```

This is my try

```
@ECHO OFF
set $FindStr=//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt#10
set $ReplString=//packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt#15

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type testlog.txt') do (
   set $Ver=%%a
   set $Ver=!$Ver: =!
   If /i !$Ver!==%$FindStr% set $Ver=%$ReplString%
   echo !$Ver! ) >> testlog.txt
```

Comment: In Windows, a command can be executed for multiple files using the `forfiles` command. The /s option tells it to search directories recursively. `forfiles /s /m *.txt /c "perl -pi -e s/search-term/replace-term/g @path"` Substitute `@path` with `/p \path\to\start\search\ ` to start the search from a different path than the current directory. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482900/recursive-search-and-replace-usind-perl-in-cmd-windows/24235368#24235368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [REPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855) script to do this. Just save it and run it like this:

```
 type testlog.txt|repl.bat "#\d\d?$" "#15"
```

If you only wanted to replace a certain number then you just need a slight modification:

```
 type testlog.txt|repl.bat "#10$" "#15"
```

If you want even more control over how things are replaced then you could use another script for that:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
COPY /A testlog.txt textlog.out.txt >nul
SET VARIABLE=0
FOR %%S IN ( 1 3 4 8 10 20 ) DO (
    SET /A VARIABLE=!VARIABLE!+1
    COPY /A textlog.out.txt textlog.tmp.txt >nul
    TYPE textlog.tmp.txt|repl.bat "#%%S$" "#!VARIABLE!" > textlog.out.txt
)
DEL textlog.tmp.txt
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply.. but i would only like to change "   //packages/thirdparty/release/main.txt            #10" and #10 can be anything. so lets assume #10 = #XX. and #15 comes from a variable.. can i use %VARIABLE%?

Comment: that is cheating a little bit, because it's not pure batch and the question did say batch. Nevertheless, it is written by a king of batch, dave benham, so repl.bat is probably as batchy as one can get for this particular problem

Comment: From your link "REPL.BAT has been superceded by JREPL.BAT, available at [viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). I am no longer maintaining REPL.BAT"

Comment: Ya, that's why I like this one better. It isn't going to change later. If you want the newer one then use that. It is very similar.